# How to get common objects from 2 querysets in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have 2 querysets of same model (obtained from different functions). Now I want to see common elements in them on the basis of some fields like:
`first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, abc_field(boolean field)`

They will have different primary keys, and unique ids. The only difference in them should be that abc_field should be True in one object and False in another object. How do I achieve this?

I read online about `annotate(Count())`, but I think this would make the code look a bit naive, with all those Count() on every field.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you custom-define a function that compares two objects. Something like:

```py
def compare(obj1, obj2):
    if (obj1.first_name == obj2.first_name && obj1.last_name == obj2.last_name ...):
        return true
    return false
```

Even if there are default methods to compare two objects, I don't think they will work in your case as you said specifically to exclude the primary key fields. The rest is simple: you loop through a double loop between your two lists and check whether the two objects are equal. Like:

```py
for item1 in list1:
    for item2 in list2:
        if compare(item1, item2):
            # ... do something
```

Pretty naive, but should work.